# pandas: select from a multi-index column dataframe with empty string returns Series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

When accessing data on a multi-index column DataFrame, pandas (v. 2.1.3) seems to "skip" empty strings in sub-levels (probably if there is no ambiguity?) returning Series instead of DataFrames:

```py
>>> df
          A         B
          1              # <- empty string under "B" 
0  0.523578  0.295221
1  0.108467  0.772837
2  0.299883  0.547574

>>> type(df['A'])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

>>> type(df['B'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Although inconsistent, this is actually a quite nice feature, as it allows somehow to programmatically implement different "depths" in a multi-index.

However, I found no mention of it either here or on the official docs, so the question is simple: can I reliably use this feature? Is this is the expected behaviour by design (and if so, is it documented somewhere?) or it might be removed in the future?

Comment: open issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11424